# Find all classes inside div except when they are in this div

Tags: jquery, html

Probably a simple one but can't get it going.

How can I:

Find all classes inside root level "Tab Container" called "on" except when they are in another nested "Tab Container". Meaning I want to be able to change Tab 1 without Tab A getting affected.

```
<ul class="Tab Container">
    <ul>
        <li<a href="#">Nav Tab 1</a></li>
    </ul>
<li class="on">Tab 1</li>
<li>Tab 2</li>
<li>Tab 3</li>
<li>
<ul class="Tab Container">
<li class="on">Tab A</li>
<li>Tab B</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Is is something to do with .not?

```
$tab.closest('.Tab Container').find('.on').not('Tab Container')
```

Thanks!

Comment: you want this when clicked on `li` inside tab?

Comment: You missed `.` inside the `closest` of `Container`

Comment: I would work with ">" So: `$tab.closest('.Tab .Container > .on')` This way you only get the "on"-classes directly in the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve it is with a selector like this

```
$('.tab-container .on:not(.tab-container .tab-container .on)')
```

it will match all the elements with `on` class which are nested in `tab-container` but not in `tab-container` which has `tab-container` parent element

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dexk8dj5/)

**please note** that writing classes with space are treated as two separate classes

Answer (score 1):

In class lists, spaces are separators.
Therefore `class="Tab Container"` gives your `ul` two classes: `Tab` and `Container`.
Accordingly you have to put a `.` in front of both when selecting an element.

In CSS selectors, a space means "inside", so `.Tab .Container` means "an element with the `Container` class somewhere inside an element with the `Tab` class".
To make it apply to the same element, remove the space:
`.Tab.Container`

Also, you can use the CSS pseudo-selector `:not` instead of calling `.not()`, which should be faster (basically the same as in [**Teneff**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30162290/2302862), but works with your HTML):

```
$('.Tab.Container .on:not(.Tab.Container .Tab.Container .on)')
```

This should apply to all elements with `class="on"` inside an element with `class="Tab Container"`, which must not be inside another element with `class="Tab Container"`.